# How do I link my HTML with my jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Firstly sorry for the post, I'm pretty new to coding, I'll try and keep it short and sweet.

Simply put, when I include my jQuery code inline, I.E. beneath my HTML, it works fine - the element I am trying to animate 'hides' and then 'shows' as it should.

However, when I make my own separate jquery.js file and put the code in there, it fails to render.

I've got the cdn script from google and included that, alongside a script and src to where my file is located inside my project folder, but still no luck.

Inside my project folder I have a 'script.js' folder, and then within that a 'jquery.js' file.

**Here's the code:**

```
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<div class="content">
  <h2> Hi there</h2>
  <h3> Take a look...</h3>
</div>
```

**Here's the jQuery:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$(".content").hide(1000).show(1000);

});

</script>
```

(Upon 'inspecting' the problem in chrome I get an error which says "jquery.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <) - But I can't see where I am mis-using a '<'.

Thanks in advance, and please feel free to tell me if I have left out anything important.

Comment: Why do you use extension for a folder name?

Comment: and why do you implement jquery two times?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I think it's just a that he wants to do jQuery but doesn't realise that by doing `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` it already works the way he wants to. Also yes. Folder name is probably the issue

Comment: They're not implementing jQuery two times, they just decided to name their custom script file `jquery.js` which could be confusing. Folder name is not the issue.

Comment: Just a side note: if you want to load jquery and make sure it is loaded (that's what it looks like), or otherwise use the local version, check out html5 boilerplate's solution: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tip about the folder name, I've changed it to 'script' now which I assume is right? Thanks a lot for the help.

Quick Q - How have I implemented jQuery two times?

Comment: You didn't. They thought that you were implementing jQuery twice because you named your custom script file `jquery.js` which implies that you were calling both a remote version of jQuery as well as a local version.

Comment: Ahh I get it now. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to remove the `<script>` tags from your jquery.js file, those are HTML tags that are used for implementing inline JS, the error you are getting is because those tags are not valid JavaScript. Your JS file should just look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content").hide(1000).show(1000);
});
```

As far as folder naming, there's nothing wrong with having a period in your folder name, but as others have suggested it would probably be a good idea to remove the `.js` part from your folder name even though it's not technically wrong and not what is causing your issue.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Will mark as my answer in about 3 minutes haha!

Comment: No problem at all, happy to help!

Answer (score -5):

Don't call your folder script.js, just call it "script".

Comment: Download all of them? I prefer the cdn because it gets cached  if you visited another site with the same cdn, most browsers don't download it again. Saves mobile data.